# Importing external file into database.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't want to check my production username and password into version control for security purposes.  If I do check it in, everyone will be able to see it.  Here is the database.yml file as it is checked into version control:

```
# /config/database.yml:
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: desk_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password_here
```

As you can see, 'password_here' is checked in as the password - but this is an invalid password if ever checked against the production database.  I basically have two options other than checking my live password into version control:

1. Save the real database.yml file on the production server in a directory above the application root.  Make a capistrano recipe to create a symbolic lync to that file when the app is deployed - this would basically overwrite the database.yml file checked into version control.
2. Save the real database.yml file (just like in option #1), but instead of making a symbolic lync, import it into database.yml file checked into version control.  This will allow the system to reference the existing file on the server each time the app is deployed without deployers worrying about changing the password or creating symbolic lyncs.  Also, I could have the permanent database.yml file which stays on the server set so the deployer can't see it...

I like the second option the most, it would basically look something like this:

```
# Config file permanently stored on the web server:
# ../app_root/database.yml (notice this is one level up from the app so it doesn't get written over)

# This is the file checked into version control:
production:
 << ../app_root/database.yml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can read it from an environment variable:

```
production:
  ...
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  ...
```

You just need to make sure that the user that starts your rails app has the environment variable set in their profile so it will be available in the `ENV` hash. For example, I often use a `deployer` user to deploy apps via capistrano, so I have `export DB_PASSWORD=the_password` set in that user's `~/.bashrc` file (of whatever is the proper place for it to go for the system you're deploying to).

This way, it's part of your source control in the sense that everyone will know where to set the password, but the password itself is not part of your source control. You'll need to keep that secret, obviously.

It wasn't immediately obvious to me either, but `.yml` files [can have embedded ruby](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/75825) in them, similar to `.erb` templates, though I have run into situations where things like this didn't work when the environment variable itself had certain special characters in it.

Comment: It’s not generally the case that `.yml` files can contain Erb. Rails [puts the contents of `database.yml` through erb before parsing it as Yaml](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.8/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L110-116).

Comment: @normalcity - this is such a cool solution, I wasn't thinking in this direction but thank you for providing an alternate solution!

Comment: @matt - thanks for the explanation of erb/yaml parsing!  Very good information, I wasn't aware of this...

Comment: @matt - Rigt, it's Rails that makes this possible. .YML files/format is independent of Rails, of course.